# What are the differences between 'let' or 'letrec' and 'define' for creating local bindings?

Tags: variables, scope, scheme, letrec

I don't understand what the differences are between (sorry for the contrived example):

```
(define average
  (lambda (elems)

   (define length
     (lambda (xs)
      (if (null? xs)
          0
          (+ 1 (length (cdr xs))))))

   (define sum
     (lambda (xs)
      (if (null? xs)
          0
          (+ (car xs) (sum (cdr xs))))))

   (define total (sum elems))

   (define count (length elems))

   (/ total count)))
```

and

```
(define average
  (lambda (elems)
   (letrec ((length
              (lambda (xs)
               (if (null? xs)
                   0
                   (+ 1 (length (cdr xs))))))

            (sum
              (lambda (xs)
               (if (null? xs)
                   0
                   (+ (car xs) (sum (cdr xs))))))

            (total (sum elems))

            (count (length elems)))

     (/ total count))))
```

As far as I can tell, they both create a new scope, and in that scope create 4 local variables that refer to each other and to themselves, and evaluate and return a body.

Am I missing something here, or is `letrec` synonymous with scoped `define`s?

*I know this may be implementation dependent; I'm trying to get an understanding of the fundamentals of Lisps.*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are correct that there are parallels between the `define` and `letrec` versions of your code. However, the devil is in the details. In R5RS, [internal `define` has `letrec` semantics](http://www.schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/r5rs-Z-H-8.html#%_sec_5.2.2). In R6RS, [internal `define` has `letrec*` semantics](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs/r6rs-Z-H-14.html#node_sec_11.3).

What's the difference? Your code has actually just highlighted this difference. As Zhehao's answer mentions, your definition of `total` and `count` inside the same `letrec` as the `length` and `sum` is incorrect: `length` and `sum` are not guaranteed to be bound by the time you're evaluating the values of `(length elems)` and `(sum elems)`, since the binding of those variables is not guaranteed to be left-to-right.

`letrec*` is similar to `letrec`, but with a left-to-right guarantee. So if you changed your `letrec` to `letrec*`, it'd be okay.

Now, back to my initial comment: because R5RS's internal `define` uses `letrec` semantics, even your `define` version of the code would be incorrect under an R5RS implementation, but it would be okay under an R6RS implementation, which has `letrec*` semantics.

Comment: Strictly speaking, `length` and `sum` are guaranteed to be *bound* (to locations); what isn't guaranteed is that they have yet been *assigned their initializing values*. And even if they have been assigned them, the Scheme reports R5RS--R7RS say it's nonetheless an "error" to be referencing those values in the way you do in the initializing clauses for `total` and `count`. (However, I don't think that implementations are required to detect and complain about this error.) Some more on differences btw `letrec`/`letrec*`: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13078165/272427

Answer (score 4):

Both let/letrec and define will create locally scoped definitions. However, let/letrec is more convenient when you aren't inside and implicit begin statement. For instance, the following code uses a let macro.

```
(define (test) (let ((x 1)) x))
```

The same code using locally scoped defines would be

```
(define test (lambda () (define x 1) x))
```

This is sort of a contrived example, but generally using let macros to do local bindings is considered more functional.

Also, your example code does not use letrec correctly. You do not need the defines inside the letrec declarations (in fact they really shouldn't be there).

Comment: Great answer! As mentioned in my answer, under R5RS, even the `define` version of the OP's code is incorrect, not just the `letrec` version.

Comment: Good point about `define` inside `letrec` ... must have been tired when I wrote that. +1